# Where can I find a list of different types of key/certificate containers and their attributes?

Tags: key, certificate

I've been working alot with asymmetric encryption and pem, cer, cert, pfx, p12 files lately and I understand some of the differences between the different containers but not all.

Where can I find a list of different types of keys/certificate containers and their attributes?

For example, I have a .cert file that I think I need to convert to .pem but I don't actually know the difference between the two or if I actually really need to convert it.

Answer (score 1):

Flip through this PDF for a bird's eye view. Past page 20 you'll find some information about containers: [What Your Mother Didn't Tell You About PEM, DER, PKCS](http://net.educause.edu/ir/library/pdf/PKI0505.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

I have found [this](https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-converter.html) to be a good resource for those kinds of questions.